# Get the users / groups inside a security level using the JIRA REST API

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to recreate the access list system in JIRA according to project and issue for all the users.
I'm already done with the issue view permission but from what I can see, I cannot get the users in a given security level in a given security scheme.

I can list the issue security level present in a project or its security scheme but I cannot get the users / groups inside it.

`GET /rest/api/2/project/{projectKeyOrId}/issuesecuritylevelscheme` is the one to call to get the security level scheme

`GET /rest/api/2/project/{projectKeyOrId}/securitylevel` is the one to list the security levels present in a project that the user ahs access to.

Old questions on the atlassian forums stated that it was impossible to get the users inside a security level. From an issue, I can get its security level so why the information is here if I can't connect it to anything else ?
Actual link : https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Retrieve-members-in-securitylevels/qaq-p/30357

I'm a bit lost currently on how to retrieve members from security level using the REST API